# How to display micro seconds using datetime datatype in mysql

Tags: mysql

How do I display the micro seconds part of a datetime when querying data from MySql 5.6+ ? Currently the default is to show the data time like 2015-09-03 08:23:50 but I want to see 2015-09-03 08:23:50.875 sometimes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use system function with length

```
SELECT sysdate(3)
```

which will display three millisecond values

```
SELECT sysdate(6)
```

which will display six millisecond values